When building and developing a Chrome extension with Vite, an additional loader.js file is generated
When building and developing a Chrome extension with Vite, an additional loader.js file is generated. The content_scripts section in manifest.json will load this loader.js file.
loader.js
(function () {
  'use strict';

  const injectTime = performance.now();
  (async () => {
    const { onExecute } = await import(
      /* @vite-ignore */
      chrome.runtime.getURL("assets/index.ts.js") <---The main content_scripts
    );
    onExecute?.({ perf: { injectTime, loadTime: performance.now() - injectTime } });
  })().catch(console.error);

})();

Is there a way to disable the generation of the loader.js file?
